# Android Studio 4.2.2 used almost 250mb internet data to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After updating to latest version of Android Studio 4.2.2 last week, I created a new project today. It was empty activity project. Earlier it didn't require Internet connection to setup new project. But this time it needed internet. So I turned on Internet and the studio kept downloading files like protos, dagger, annotation etc. and almost 250mb of files were downloaded. Is it first time only or I'll use data for creating new project every time

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not include all the different gradle and Gradle-Android-plugin versions as well as all the common compatibility libraries used by a standard Android Studio project. 250Mb download is therefore nothing unusual for a first start. Once the data has been downloaded once it is cached in your user home so it will not be downloaded again.

Recent gradle versions alone have a download size of ~100MB. Working with multiple Android Studio projects of different age can require each project to use (and therefore download) a different version of Gradle, Gradle-Android-plugin and so on.

Some very old Android SDK versions came with an offline repo containing the most important libraries. But Google switched to their own online Google Maven repository as the number of files in that repo is growing fast and thus providing it as an offline version in Android SDK is not really feasible anymore.